# Append key value pair to angularjs object

Tags: angularjs

I am getting json output from laravel 5.2 form request validation

My json output is:

```
{
    "title": [
        "The title field is required."
    ],
    "description": [
        "The description field is required."
    ],
    "address.city": [
        "City field is required"
    ]
}
```

Appending this output to object

```
var self = this;
self.error = {
    address: {}
};

var onFailure = function (response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
        self.error[key] = value[0];
    });
};
```

I want to access this error object to my view, for "address.city", I can't access it using "ctrl.error.address.city", rest I can access

How to append object with key containing "." and show it in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need. But its better not to have (.) in a property name. Instead you can use a underscore(_). Avoid using dot(.) as a chaaracter in property names.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.foo={};
    $scope.foo['hello.There'] = "I'm foo!";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{foo["hello.There"]}}<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo['hello.There']" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the key name then the only way you can access it is by `[]`.

Check the fiddle for more info.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/9f4mbh1h/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to this

in your controller

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.foo={};
$scope.foo "hi";
  });
```

in html

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="foo" /> </div>
```